# Red X appears over PNGs in IE

Tags: asp.net, image, internet-explorer

I've got this web site written in ASP/C#, and when I display images through ASP code like:

```
<img src="images/someImg.png" id="Img1" alt="" align="top" border="0" width="295" height="35" style="position:absolute;left:327px; top:545px; width:295px;height:35px;z-index:11" />
```

The problem is, in every other browser the page looks perfect, but in IE, images are displayed and on top of them there is the little red X which is shown when the picture is missing.  The picture is obviously not missing because it is shown in *every* browser, but in IE it is shown and there is the "missing picture" X on top of it.

Most solutions on the web suggest adding a "./image/..." or "~/image/..." but I've tried it and it doesn't work.

Also, when I display images from a database in any kind of default ASP.net data viewer (e.g. DetailsView) some of the pictures are shown normally, some with the little X on top.  Again, this is *only* in IE, and *only* with images with .png extension.  In every other browser it looks fine.  I even got the page validated and it works perfectly.

Does anybody know a solution?

I tried a couple of PNG fixes I could find and still nothing.

PS: I'm currently running the page locally.  Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link I found the solution

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/